# Rails + Griddler + Sidekiq as processor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, griddler

Is that possible to use Sidekiq to perform as Griddler Processor ? Currently Griddler return a Griddler Object that I can't send to Sidekiq, and I need it to upload attachments to S3 Bucket.

Do you have any way to use Griddler with Sidekiq ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the griddler object to a hash and send that to Sidekiq.  Make sure Sidekiq and Rails are running on the same machine so Sidekiq can access the attachment path on the filesystem.

Comment: The problem is with attachments that are Tempfile. Do I have any chance to loose those files if I have a huge queue ?

Comment: Ok I did it. Now I persist my Tempfiles and send path to the worker then upload them. Thanks !